# Unix - Permission denied

Tags: unix

I created two files in Unix, say `filename1` and `filename2`. I am able to see the contents of both the files. But when I am executing one command

```
filename1 >& filename2
```

I am not able to open the file `filename2`. It is throwing error

```
/.filename1 : Permission denied.
```

Complete code:

```
bash-4.3$ cat>filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat> filename2
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename2
Hi all
bash-4.3$ filename1 >& filename2
bash-4.3$ cat filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename2
bash: ./filename1:Permission denied
```

Comment: what's "/" before filename1?

Comment: Show the output of `ls -l filename1 filename2`(if in the current directory)

Comment: @Am_I_helpful -rw-r--r-- for both files

Comment: The error message, particularly the leading `/.`, is inconsistent with the command. Please copy-and-paste the exact command and the exact error message. And please tell us what shell you're using (bash? tcsh?).

Comment: @Keith Thompson : bash-4.3$ cat>filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat> filename2
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename2
Hi all
bash-4.3$ filename1 >& filename2
bash-4.3$ cat filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename2
bash: ./filename1:Permission denied

Comment: @KeithThompson This is full command I had written

Comment: Please edit your question with that information. It's difficult to read without proper formatting.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
chmod +x filename1
chmod +w filename2
```

Need to check your clobber setting as well. This depends on the shell being used. Google it!

**EDIT**

For bash

```
set +o noclobber
```

Then you can overwrite files. Not a good idea

Comment: Why is it useless - setting the execute bit for the script?

Comment: @EdHeal: Never mind, I didn't notice that `filename1` is an executable. I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Apparently `filename1` is (intended to be) an executable shell script. `filename2` contains the output from executing that script.

```
bash-4.3$ cat>filename1
Hi all
```

This creates a file named `filename1` containing a single line of text, `Hi all`.

```
bash-4.3$ cat> filename2
Hi all
```

The same for `filename2`.

```
bash-4.3$ cat filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename2
Hi all
```

And you verify their contents.

```
bash-4.3$ filename1 >& filename2
```

This attempts to execute `filename1`, redirecting both its stdout and stderr to `filename2`.

Since you haven't done `chmod +x filename1`, you get a "Permission denied" error when you try to execute it.  Even if you had done the `chmod`, it wouldn't work, because `filename1` is not a valid script (unless you happen to have a command named `Hi`).  More on that below.

```
bash-4.3$ cat filename1
Hi all
bash-4.3$ cat filename2
bash: ./filename1:Permission denied
```

`filename2` contains the output (none) and error message you got when you tried to execute `filename1`.  The previous contents of `filename2` were clobbered, which means there was no point in creating it in the first place.

Bash does support the `>&` syntax to redirect both stdout and stderr, but it's not recommended. `&>` is preferred (at least according to the bash documentation). Or, more explicitly, you could write `filename1 >filename2 2>&1`.

The fact that you were able to execute the script by typing just `filename1` indicates that you have `.`, the current directory, in your `$PATH`. That's a bad idea. (Having `.` at the front of your `$PATH` is particularly dangerous.) You should remove `.` from your `$PATH`; if you want to execute a command in the current directory, prefix it with `./`.

Here's how do to something similar what you *seem* to be trying to do:

```
$ cat > script
#!/bin/bash

echo Hi all
$ chmod +x script
$ ./script &> output
$ cat output
Hi all
$
```

Note the `#!/bin/bash` I added to the top of the script.  Every executable script should have a `#!` line to specify how it's executed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understood the issue  and where I was doing wrong.Since I have just started learning Unix, I was not able to understand output of that command.